# 403 Forbidden error in phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run rails application on ubuntu14.04 , after installing phpMyAdmin , nginx unable to load phpmyadmin

nginx error log

```
nginx/html/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your Nginx conf.d folder (For Ubuntu location is **/etc/nginx/conf.d**) create one **default.conf** file if not already available and put the below code block. Sample conf file you can check [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/example.html). You can use the server block to begin with.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: You can accept the answer so that others can find it helpful